# Java - default option does not fuction in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, java.util.scanner, default

hello I wrote a program to convert one temperature from one to another using switch.

**the default does not fuction**:

When i enter a valid option it works perfectly fine, but when i choose invalid choice it goes the default outputting the lines: **You enter invalid choice, please choose again** and stop workings without allowing me to choose another choice.

earlier when I tested it, the default allowed me to choose another option.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tempature {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fahrenheit,celcius,kelvin;
        System.out.println("Choose type of temperature:\nf. Fahrenheit\nc. Celcius\nk. Kelvin");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        switch(word){
            case "f": System.out.println("Enter  Fahrenheit temperature: ");
            fahrenheit=scan.nextDouble();
            celcius = (fahrenheit-32) * 5/9;
            kelvin = (fahrenheit + 459.67) * 5/9;
            System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
            System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
            System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
            break;
            case "c": System.out.println("Enter the Celcius temperature: ");
            celcius=scan.nextDouble();
            fahrenheit = (celcius*9)/5 + 32;
            kelvin = celcius + 273.15;
            System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
            System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
            System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
            break;
            case "k": System.out.println("Enter the Kelvin temperature: ");
            kelvin=scan.nextDouble();
            fahrenheit = 1.8*(kelvin - 273.15) + 32;
            celcius = kelvin - 273.15;
            System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
            System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
            System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
            break;
            default: System.out.println("You enter invalid choice, please choose again");
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working" what do you expect it to do after it has handled the default case?  what happens after you enter a valid option, does it continue to work?

Comment: when I enter a valid option it continue to work fine, earlier write testing it the default option allow me to choose again another option, this time it doesn't let me choose just stop the program.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that allows the user to enter more than one choice, when you chose c/f/k it allows one value to be entered then the program ends.  As written your programming is working correctly.  To allow the user to choose a second....n option there needs to be some sort of loop.  Perhaps do a google search on Java command line applications that accept user input.

Comment: That is exactly what you have written for it to follow. when an invalid character is typed, it will print the statement as you have mentioned and will exit. If you want it to keep prompting you until you enter a valid character, you may try using a do-while loop.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to move the code that is repeated/duplicated into a method.

Comment: okk I understand, can you help me with writing the loop please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help you.
add a `while` loop and read the input of user in `default` and it will work
.
When user puts `q` he/she will exit the program.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fahrenheit,celcius,kelvin;
        // changed
        System.out.println("Choose type of temperature:\nf. Fahrenheit\nc. Celcius\nk. Kelvin\nq. Quit");
        String word = scan.next();
        
        //added
        while(!word.equals("q")) {
            
            switch(word){
                case "f": {
                    System.out.println("Enter  Fahrenheit temperature: ");
                    fahrenheit=scan.nextDouble();
                    celcius = (fahrenheit-32) * 5/9;
                    kelvin = (fahrenheit + 459.67) * 5/9;
                    System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
                    System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
                    System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
                    break;
                }
                case "c":{
                    System.out.println("Enter the Celcius temperature: ");
                    celcius=scan.nextDouble();
                    fahrenheit = (celcius*9)/5 + 32;
                    kelvin = celcius + 273.15;
                    System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
                    System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
                    System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
                    break;
                }
                case "k": {
                    System.out.println("Enter the Kelvin temperature: ");
                    kelvin=scan.nextDouble();
                    fahrenheit = 1.8*(kelvin - 273.15) + 32;
                    celcius = kelvin - 273.15;
                    System.out.println("" + celcius + " C");
                    System.out.println("" + fahrenheit + " F");
                    System.out.println("" + kelvin + " K");
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    System.out.println("You enter invalid choice, please choose again");
                    // added
                    System.out.println("Choose type of temperature:\nf. Fahrenheit\nc. Celcius\nk. Kelvin\nq.Quit");
                    word = scan.next();
                    break;
                    }
                }// end of swtich
            // checking for exit
            if(!word.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("Choose type of temperature:\nf. Fahrenheit\nc. Celcius\nk. Kelvin\nq. Quit");
                word = scan.next();
            }
        }// end of while
        System.out.println("Exited");
            }
    }
```

Output:

```
Choose type of temperature:
f. Fahrenheit
c. Celcius
k. Kelvin
q. Quit
f
Enter  Fahrenheit temperature: 
45
7.222222222222222 C
45.0 F
280.3722222222222 K
Choose type of temperature:
f. Fahrenheit
c. Celcius
k. Kelvin
q. Quit
c
Enter the Celcius temperature: 
45
45.0 C
113.0 F
318.15 K
Choose type of temperature:
f. Fahrenheit
c. Celcius
k. Kelvin
q. Quit
k
Enter the Kelvin temperature: 
45
-228.14999999999998 C
-378.66999999999996 F
45.0 K
Choose type of temperature:
f. Fahrenheit
c. Celcius
k. Kelvin
q. Quit
cdvd
You enter invalid choice, please choose again
Choose type of temperature:
f. Fahrenheit
c. Celcius
k. Kelvin
q.Quit
q
Exited
```

Comment: and what will happen after the user enters a value to be converted? can they enter a second option? or can they only enter a second option if they have entered an invalid option.  Perhaps a better solution is to move ```word = scan.nextLine()``` outside of the switch and before the end of the loop?

Comment: Or if you just want to stop after a successful operation: `word != "f" && word != "c" && word != "k"`. Or even better add a variable outside the loop which tracks whether the loop should continue or not.

Comment: someone answered my question about the successfull operation so I edited, ty verymuch guys very helpfull :)

Comment: Have made the edits take a look. Now it worked all fine.